Microsoft Social Login Approval Required Popup
The following image is the issue I am facing while trying to add Social Login with microsoft.

Since I am not the global admin of the tenant, I've had to reach out to them for permissions and other settings that I am unable to change by myself.
I have tried the following things so far:

Enabling "Allow User Consent for Apps" in Enterprise Applications => Consent & Permissions => User Consent Settings

Adding a proper Redirect URI in the  App Registration=>"MyApp/Authentication" section

I also tried to get the global admin to allow consent through the following URL, but they did not get the prompt to allow permissions at all

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=%7Bmy-client-id%7D



I have explored pretty much every document I could find regarding this issue, and the farthest I got was to change a few permissions, which I am unable to do because I am not the global admin.
It is worth mentioning that out of the two permissions in the below image, even though the admin has enabled and saved both, the first one is still not showing up on the account I am using, and I don't know why.

I am not sure how to proceed with this since I am completely new to Azure

Could you click on Admin consent settings in Enterprise Applications => Consent & Permissions and add that snip by editing your question?

To resolve the error, you need to either approve Admin consent request where Global Administrator access is required or disable this option in user's directory like this https://i.imgur.com/9Lwg9tg.png

The admin consent settings are the same as what your attached image shows, here it is:
https://imgur.com/a/08CWzdl @Sridevi

Could you confirm whether your app registration is multi-tenant or not? If it's multi-tenant, you need to check the tenant settings in which user is signing in.

While signing in, Approval required popup will occur if below setting is enabled to Yes in that tenant:

When I tried to sign in with above setting enabled, I too got  Approval required popup like this:

To avoid this Approval required popup, you need to disable below option by setting it to No in your tenant:

In User consent settings, I enabled "Allow user consent for apps" option as below:

When I tried to sign in again after changing above settings, I got below consent screen without need of entering justification:

Alternatively, ask your admin to grant consent by visiting Permissions tab of your Enterprise Application here:

References:
java - MS Login API asking for Admin consent for registering with MS azure App - Stack Overflow
Azure SSO- How to remove approval required screen after sign in - Stack Overflow

thanks. but after giving the consent, we have the auth code, I  exchanged the auth code for the access token. but when this access_token is used, I am having this error - {
"error": {
"code": "MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI",
"message": "The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise."
}
}

Hi @Abhishek Please post a new question with more details on your requirement by including this complete error and share question link here

No worries. I found a fix. I was passing the tenant id with the auth code request. using 'common' instead of the tenant id fixed the issue and returned proper access_token.
